# Opencart: Change page ID path

Tags: opencart

I'm trying to make my site more *SEO friendly* and I'm noticing that whenever I go to a product through either a tag or a different page (2,3,4 etc) that it adds it to the URL.

For example:

```
www.domain.com/Guardian-Survival-kit/culinary-can-of-preparedness-seeds.html?page=2
```

I would like to remove `?page=2` from the path

Opencart 1.5.4

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually edit the code for each pre-product controller file (such as search pages etc) or you could use something like [this modification](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=5023) that will make all of your product URL's consistent throughout your installation. As an example, I think the page you're getting those off is in the product search page, so you would open `/catalog/controller/product/search.php`

Find this code

```
'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', $url . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
```

And change it to

```
'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
```

Then save. Be sure to make a backup for this file before attempting this change. This will remove any additional parameters to the URL and simply have the product URL